# How to find Gaps between road segments in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have huge data and want to find out gaps between segments. Although I have used Near tool and found some results but not a clear picture.

Comment: If you have at least a Standard license, you can create a [topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/topologies/an-overview-of-topology-in-arcgis.htm) with the "Must Not Have Dangles" rule.

Comment: If you used the Near tool in ArcGIS I assume you have the Advanced license.  Then I presume you can also use the Features Vertices to Points tool and focus on dangles.  I've never actually used that tool since I've had and used the ET Geowizards Nodes tool to this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ET geowizards you can clean up gaps using the Clean Contours tool, then if you use the ArcGIS erase tool you can subtract the original from the cleaned feature class and it will give you the gaps between segments.